# waiting a function to complete

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions. The second one is faster than the first one,how could the function wait to  complete first one's work?

```
function1(); // slow 

function2(); // fast
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is imperative and single-threaded, it just *works* like this. `function2()` won't start until `function1()` finishes.

If by *slow* you mean calling asynchronously some external service via AJAX, then we're talking. `function1()` must provide some sort of callback so that when asynchronous request finishes, `function2()` is called:

```
function1(function2);
```

The implementation is trivial, e.g. using jQuery:

```
function function1(callback) {
  $.ajax({url: 'some-url'}).done(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be using some AJAX request. So, after ajax complete call callback function like:

```
function1 = new function(callback) {
    $.ajax({...}).done(callback());
}

function1(function2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If functions are to be called asynchronously, aside from the obvious callback approach, their sequencing could be based on the events framework. You could add an event listener with function1 as a handler, and trigger that event within function2.

Comment: @downvoter Could you please also leave a comment explaining the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, I also got -1. Seems like all answers here were downvoted, except [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13100082/605744). Hmmm...

Answer (score -1):

If your calling one function after the other then it will finish the first either it may be slow or fast.