# Need help implementing the sequencing of jquery instructions

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

The problem: I have a simple function and I need the instructions within it to take place one at a time. Here it is:

```
showImages = (current_time, exercise) ->
  $('#slideshow img.active').first().fadeOut(500).removeClass('active')
  $('#new-image').addClass('active')
```

Since the last 2 lines happen almost simultaneously, the image with id 'new-image' gets faded out.

I would like the line processing the img with the class 'active' to be completed before the next line kicks in.

I have done lots of Google searching but I don't know how to apply the code examples to this use case. Here are some Google articles I found:

- [jQuery: wait for function to complete to continue processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455870/jquery-wait-for-function-to-complete-to-continue-processing)
- http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?847638-Script-to-Wait-for-javascript-function-to-end
- [waiting a function to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100057/waiting-a-function-to-complete)

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"Since the last 2 lines happen almost simultaneously, the image with id 'new-image' gets faded out."_ - That doesn't make sense. The line `$('#slideshow img.active').first().fadeOut(500).removeClass('active')` selects the first `img.active` element (within `#slideshow`) and queues up a fadeOut on it before immediately removing its `'active'` class. The fadeOut takes 500ms, but will apply _only_ to that element, it doesn't somehow also apply to other elements that may have the `'active'` class added while the fade is still happening.

Comment: P.S. Is there other code that you're not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`fadeOut()` method](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) has a *complete* callback which can be used as a function:

> `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`

This can be used as:

```
$(elem).fadeOut(500, function() { ... });
```

Therefore, in your case you can simply:

```
$('#slideshow img.active').first().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('#new-image').addClass('active');
});
```

With this, the currently `.active` element will lose its class and the `#new-image` will gain the active class *after* the `fadeOut()` has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) complete function:

```
$('#slideshow img.active').first().fadeOut(500, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $('#new-image').addClass('active');
});
```

Any code within the `complete` function is executed when the animation has finished

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this helps. heres a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEUcN/)

```
    $('#slideshow img.active').first()
    .fadeOut(500).removeClass('active')
    .setTimeout(function(){
      $('#new-image').addClass('active')
    },100);
```

Comment: Thanks Lewis. I used the another answer as I prefe to avoid going the setTimeout road.